# Who has the guide for dropCam iPhone library

Tags: iphone, video-streaming

I have downloaded the dropCam iPhone library from https://github.com/dropcam/dropcam_for_iphone.

But I have no guide. There are no README.

There are libDropcam.a and lib folder.

I need to use the library over all including ffmpeg.

I can not compile Decoder Wrapper because of ffmpeg library.

So I am going to use the libDropcam.a.

How use this libary?